# New HTML 5 MONTH INPUT TYPE and IE 11 compatibility

Tags: html, internet-explorer

I'd like to take advantage of a new HTML 5 Input type for entering a month/year. A working example is shown here. Warning. You may have to use Chome or something other than IE to see it.

http://www.w3schools.com/htmL/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_input_month

The code is pasted here:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p>
Depending on browser support:<br>
A date picker can pop-up when you enter the input field.
</p>

<form action="action_page.php">
  Birthday (month and year):
  <input type="month" name="bdaymonth">
  <input type="submit">
</form>

<p><strong>Note:</strong> type="month" is not supported in Internet Explorer 10 and earlier versions.</p>

</body>
</html>
```

Our company is on IE9 and should be upgrading to IE 11 soon. I have IE 11 on the computer that I am using at the moment and I don't see any drop down calendar of any sort, just a plain text box for input.If IE 11 supported it, I would start developing with it. However, I wanted to see how it worked, because this input type seems to behave really poorly with IE9. Chrome seems to require a YYYY/MM/DD format for the input *value* property and while IE 9 will display this value in the same format, Chrome will display it using the local settings. I wanted to see how things look in IE 11. Surprise! no calendar!

Wouldnt you expect IE 11 to support this input type or am I missing something? The referenced link suggests IE supports it but they didn't say which version. I wouldn't expect that only Edge would...

Chrome displays the Month Year using the Name of the Month. Is there a way to get it to control the format and perhaps display in MM YYYY format? where MM = a 1 or 2 digit month number?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Input type -month is currently supported only in Chrome ,Opera and Safari

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/Input

Comment: I guess the W3 schools link had it wrong. They showed the IE icon. Any idea if you can control the format of the date in Chome?

Comment: you can't change format for type-month, but you can try something like- http://codepen.io/nagasai/pen/KrBvRY